# Prestashop. Get combinations of a product

Tags: smarty, combinations, prestashop

How can i get a combination of a product. I need to get a color of a product in cart with smarty. I guess i need to rewrite the controller, but i have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to re-write the controller.  Go into catalog->product attributes

Add a color attribute - then go in to the attribute and add your colors.

Now go to your product and add that as a combination to that product - each product can have multiple combinations, or in your case colors.

Dave